# Order top level categories without using drag and drop admin function

Tags: magento-1.7, navigation, category-tree

Currently need to position a new category between two existing top level categories.

Can't use the drag and drop feature in the admin as it seems to cause rewrite and duplication issues. Is their a way I can sort these top level categories?

My top.phtml appears as :

```
<?php $_menu = $this->renderCategoriesMenuHtml(0,'level-top') ?>

<?php if($_menu): ?>
   <div class="nav-container">
       <ul id="nav">
           <?php echo $_menu ?>
       </ul>
   </div>
<?php endif ?>
```